# Exactly what does env do in Bash?

Tags: bash

I get this behavior when using Bash (under Cygwin):

```
$ printf '\u00d5'
\u00d5
$ env printf '\u00d5' # This results in the behavior I want
Õ
```

It does not matter if I use UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1 encoding in the terminal.

My questions are: Exactly what does **env** do? Why do I need it in this specific case?

Comment: Interesting find. Something similar happens on Linux. I just get `?` (= unknown Unicode character) for the first case but I get the same result for the second case.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`env` is not in `bash`, it's a standalone executable, it is used to set or clear environment variable before running program. In your particular case, it's running the binary `printf` instead of the shell builtin. You can achieve the same result by using the absolute path:

```
/usr/bin/printf '\u00d5'
```

---

The least intrusive method is perhaps the following: redefine the `printf` function and have Bash handle the rest. Source a file that contains the following:

```
function printf()
{
  $(which printf) "$@"
}
```

or as a one-liner `function printf() { $(which printf) "$@"; }`. Of course you could replace the `$(which printf)` for a `/usr/bin/printf` ...

Then simply use printf as you're used to. Your script stays the same and you could even introduce a condition to define the function only on certain Bash versions.

AFAIK you can also leave out the `function`, but I find it adds to readability.

[EDIT: the `function` keyword is a `bash` extension; `printf () { ...; }` is the POSIX syntax. If you do use the `function` keyword, the () after the function name are optional.]

---

Commonly, `env` is also used in the hash-bang lines of scripts that strive to be portable. The reason being that `env` is nearly always at `/usr/bin/env`, while `bash` isn't always at `/bin/bash` as many a hash-bang line implies. Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

also works for other programs/interpreters:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Comment: +1 I was just about to post the same thing, having confirmed on a Linux box.

Comment: Thanks for confirming it, I was just going to try ;-)

Comment: I'm wondering why the bash builtin doesn't correctly handle `\u` :-/ According to the help page (`help printf`), it should behave like the binary and the man page for the binary (`man printf`) says "\uHHHH Unicode (ISO/IEC 10646) character with hex value HHHH (4 digits)"

Comment: Hm. Builtin outputs question mark on linux… I'm not sure what it's trying to say. my locale is utf8…

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: I added a bash-internal alternative ;) ... `command` is the opposite of `builtin`, which can both be used to "prefix" the following command and result in execution of either the external or the bash-internal version of a command.

Comment: Some versions of Bash had a bug in `printf`'s `\u` handling. Which Bash version do you have?

Comment: Now I'm lost. @0xC0000022L — it doesn't work. And `"printf" '\u00d5'` also doesn't.

Comment: `command` only suppresses shell function lookup. It still prefers a builtin command over an external program.

Comment: @chepner — what about quotes? I didn't look up the docs for a while, but I know I used it to run `time` command instead of `time` builtin. It doesn't help here.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: you're right. `command` kind of "unaliases" the command following it. Apparently this is a misconception of mine. So if you have `alias ssh="ssh -A"` then running `ssh` will invoke `ssh -A`, but running `command ssh` will invoke simply `ssh`.

Comment: Yeah and I think I've been messing with my memory re- quoting the command :)