# what exactly env command do?

Tags: bash, shell, shellshock-bash-bug

i recently came across the shellshock bug, which is a bug in the bash shell. somehow it uses the `env` command to create environment variables containing functions.

```
$ env x='() { :;}; echo vulnerable' bash -c "echo this is a test"
```

These functions then run when a new bash shell is spawned. i read at many places and got the same explanation that i just wrote. But i still cannot make out the working of the above command along with its parameters. **can anyone explain?**

Comment: @JakeGould: i read the posts and discussion through the internet, cudnt find a thorough explanation

Comment: `man env`? It's just a way to trigger the bug; knowing how `env` works isn't going to explain how the exploit itself works.

Comment: Arguably, a better duplicate would be [Exactly what does `env` do in Bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12691461/exactly-what-does-env-do-in-bash).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`env` sets one or more environment variables and then runs the remaining arguments as a command.

It's not significantly different from the following syntax:

```
x='() { :;}; echo vulnerable' bash -c "echo this is a test"
```

One thing `env` can do (although the feature is not used in the above example) is create a clean environment; if the first option to `env` is a single `-` (or `-i`), then the environment is cleaned before doing the explicit assignments and running the command.

Comment: Is that the only difference between using env and not using it (i.e. ability to start with a blank environment)?

Comment: @jeremy: normally, yes. `env` is often used in a shebang lines (`#!/bin/env ...`) because it searches `PATH` for the executable, but that only matters in places where `PATH` is not searched.

Comment: I should add  that PATH is not searched in shebang lines for a good reason and the "workaround" is not a good idea IMHO. But that is way out if scope here.